# Year and month in a crystal report

Tags: date, crystal-reports

I have designed student ID Card using crystal report version 13_0_9 for visual studio 2013.

There 2 fields on student ID card that reflect year and month. For the field year I need to show it as 2015 - 2016. And for month it need show as June To May.

I tried placing two special fields for year, month and formatted to show only year and month value.

But the fields reflect only current year and month, how do I achieve this to reflect year as 2015 - 2016 and month as June To May. See below Image.

https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=9F3DE61006533307&id=9f3de61006533307%211621&v=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A formula called Year:

```
cstr(Year (CurrentDateTime),"#") & '-' & Right(cstr(Year (CurrentDateTime) + 1 ,"#"),2);
```

and one called Month

```
cstr(CurrentDateTime,"MMM") & ' to ' & cstr(DateAdd("m",11,DateAdd("y", 1, CurrentDateTime)),"MMM")
```

I'm on Crystal standalone but should work equally in VS 2013